# Is it possible to make customized UITableViewCellSelectionStyleMyColor in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, customization

I know I could follow [this tutorial](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) to develop very customized grouped tableview in iOS, but it's far different from original UI and what I would like to implement is simply change the selected color(with gradient) other than UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue and Gray.

Moreover, it's slightly different if I manually set the cell background view color, the frame is not displayed when selected.

So, is it possible to just extend the enum of UITableViewCellSelectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleOrange or Red or Pink?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

To change that, you will need to set the selected cell background view in your TableViewController.

```
self.selectedCellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.selectedCellBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

iOS enums are not modifiable.